# Fixed arrow size in parametric 3d plot

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to add arrows to a trajectory in `ParametrcPlot3D`

```
    ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Cos[t] Sin[t], t}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All] /. 
 Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0}], Arrow[x]}
```

The arrow that I obtain change with the 3d view. the closer ones look larger and the further ones look small. how can I have the size of the arrow fixed for all 3d views?

Update: It is important that the size of the arrow can be controlled, i.e, the symbolic presentation of `Tiny` to`Large` are not sufficient.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could use a custom glyph, like this:

```
Manipulate[
 h = Graphics[Triangle[{{0, -0.3}, {a, 0}, {0, 0.3}}]];
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Cos[t] Sin[t], t}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All] /. 
  Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0, {size, Automatic, h}, {size, Automatic, 
       h}, {size, Automatic, h}, {size, Automatic, h}, 0}, 
     Appearance -> "Projected"], Arrow[x]}, {{size, 6}, 4, 
  20}, {{a, 1}, 0.1, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are doing essentially the same thing that I suggested, that is, using sizes that are much larger than 1.

Comment: I just added an option to increase the length of the arrow (triangles)

Comment: @M.R, when the image is rotated, the size of the arrows change.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the symbolic sizes to create arrowheads that have a fixed size:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
    {Cos[t],Cos[t] Sin[t],t},
    {t,0,10},
    BoxRatios->{1,1,1},
    PlotRange->All
] /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0,Large,Large,Large,Large,0}], Arrow[x]}
```

[image]

**Addendum**

I don't know of any documented method to generated fixed arrow head sizes other than using the symbolic values [`Tiny`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tiny), [`Small`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Small), etc. However, it seems that using a size greater than 10 or so will generate an arrow head with a fixed size, presumably in pixels. So:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
    {Cos[t],Cos[t] Sin[t],t},
    {t, 0, 10},
    BoxRatios->{1, 1, 1},
    PlotRange->All
] /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0,40,40,40,40,0}],Arrow[x]}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make them fixed in a size that is much larger then the symbolic size Large?

Comment: @jarhead See update

Comment: thanks for the update and the effort, but this way around does not solve the problem yet. In other plots your suggestions, Arrow size Large/40, appear extremely too small/large.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: @jarhead An example plot where my suggestions don't help would be useful.