# Weird Arrowhead behaviour when playing with BoxRatios->1

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Basically the arrowhead is dependent on the scaling, and I would like it so that it wasn't the case, for example when `α` is 1

[image: normal]

Then the arrowhead is displayed as it should, but as I slide `α`, then I get these kind of artifacts

[image: a big arrow across the whole graphic]

The code for the manipulate that I am using is

```
Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot3D[
    {x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. 
      {{x -> Function[{t}, a + b t α], 
        y -> Function[{t}, b], 
        z -> Function[{t}, c E^(t α)]}} /. 
        a -> 1 /. 
        b -> 2 /. 
        c -> 10, 
    {t, 0, 25}, 
    PlotRange -> All,
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, 
    BoxRatios -> 1,
    PlotStyle -> 
      Directive[{Red, Arrowheads[.000000000004]}]] /. 
    Line[pts_] :> Arrow[Line[pts], {0, -.1}], 
  {α, -10, 10}]
```

How can I fix the arrows so that I don't get the artifacts while manipulating?

In [the other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180538) it was suggested to use `Small`, `Medium` or `Large`, or maybe use a numeric value to change the arrows size numerically. However, when using `Medium` or `Large`, this is what happens

[image: This is what happens when I use medium or size]

However, it does seem to work fine on certain perspectives and with a negative value of `α`.

[image: now it works ok]

If I change the perspective or rotate the graphic, then it becomes a mess.

So, okay, I already know I can change the size of the arrows numerically, that is good to know, but is there any way to know what is the best size for the arrow, so that the arrow appears the same size with different scalings of the plot? Besides, it seems that when I rotate the cube or change the perspective, the arrowhead dramatically changes the size, why does this happen?

Comment: In Details and Options of Arrowheads one can read: `The symbolic values Tiny, Small, Medium, and Large can be used for s. With these values, the size of the arrowhead is independent of the total width of the graphic.` So, you can set `Medium` or `Large` in place of your .000000000004.

Comment: I attempted with Large, medium and small, but no arrow shows up anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed arrow size in parametric 3d plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180538/fixed-arrow-size-in-parametric-3d-plot)

Comment: I've edited the question to explain how this is different from that question. And that the accepted answer on that question doesn't solve my problem, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the result of forcing the z-axis to rescale over 200 orders of magnitude as`α` is varied from -10 to +10. This appears to be beyond what Mathematica's 3D graphics engine can handle. When the range of `α` is restricted to something reasonable there is no problem. The critical value of `α`, the value at which the rendering begins to go bad, is at about `α = 3.4`.

Here is demonstration that I believe shows the problem better than the OP's examples.

```
With[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 10, tmax = 25, αmax = 4},
  Manipulate[
    ParametricPlot3D[{a + b Cos[2 π t/tmax], b Sin[2 π t/tmax], c E^(t α)}, {t, 0, max},
      PlotRange -> All,
      BoxRatios -> 1,
      PlotStyle -> Directive[{Red, Arrowheads[Medium]}]] 
    /. 
      Line[pts_] :> Arrow[Line[pts], {0, -.1}],
    {{α, 0}, -1, αmax, .05, ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Just to show picture, probably not complete answer:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], 
        z[t]} /. {{x -> Function[{t}, a + b t α], 
         y -> Function[{t}, b], 
         z -> Function[{t}, c E^(t α)]}} /. a -> 1 /. 
     b -> 2 /. c -> 10, {t, 0, 25}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, AspectRatio -> 1, BoxRatios -> 1, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[{Red, Arrowheads[Large]}]] /. 
  Line[pts_] :> Arrow[Line[pts]], {α, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

This is for `α = 2.25`, and I rotated box with mouse a little to clearly see arrow head.

Comment: Which mathematica version are you using? It doesn't seem to work in mathematica 11.0 for windows

Comment: Ah, it may be version depedent, I use Mathematica 12, Windows.